# Scala: Defining Primary Key in Data Frame

Tags: apache-spark, primary-key, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to define the Primary Key when using the Data Frame? 
I have two data frames, which I have joined on "ID". Now I want to select "Date" and also received the primary key "ID" in the output.

```
val join1 = df_2.join(df_3, df_3.col("ID") === df_2.col("APPLICATION2_ID")) 
val joinFinal = join1.join(df_1, df_1.col("ID") === join1.col("ID"))
```

Comment: DataFrames do not have the concept of a primary key, and what you are suggesting should work...what exactly have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: val join1 = df_2.join(df_3, df_3.col("ID") === df_2.col("APPLICATION2_ID"))
    val joinFinal = join1.join(df_1, df_1.col("ID") === join1.col("ID"))            I have 3 data frames, which I joined and all the data frames have the column "ID". Now I am trying to perform a transformation.                    val df_Move =joinFinal.select("ID","Date"). However due to the multiple columns called "ID", I am getting a ambiguous ID error.

Comment: @SFatima And what's the error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'ID' is ambiguous, could be: ID#132,ID#0

Answer (score 2):

In order to get rid of duplicate columns when joining on same named ones use the Seq version:

```
val joinFinal = join1.join(df_1, Seq("ID"))
```